# jQuery script doesn't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a simple jQuery script to manage a form. I have inserted the code in the header using the script `$(window).load(function(){...`
But the script doesn't work if the function `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` is called. If I try to remove it my script works.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: post the full code. else only god can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** use `$(window).load(function(){...` in Wordpress!

You need a no-conflict DOM ready wrapper, as Wordpress is in no-conflict mode by default :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // your code goes here
    $('#myElementID').css('color', 'red'); // example
});
```

And make sure the script is included after the jQuery file, which you would normally do by using dependencies in `wp_enque_script()`